# Update scroll area dynamically in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I have this code pen of an ionic project.

It just displays an image for now and I've made two buttons to zoom in and out.

The problem is when I click zoom in and scroll to the very right or bottom right, then click zoom out... The scroll area does not update and i'm left with a white screen.

If I then click the screen once, the scroll area adjusts!

How can I make this happen automatically?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaGeeg

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  // get image-holder details
  $scope.imageHolderDetails = document.getElementById('img-holder').getBoundingClientRect();
  $scope.imageHolderWidth = $scope.imageHolderDetails.width;

  // get image
  $scope.image = document.getElementById('image');

  //set zoom amount to image-holder width x 2
  $scope.zoomAmount = $scope.imageHolderDetails.width * 2;

  // set the image to full width of image-holder
  $scope.image.style.width = $scope.imageHolderWidth + 'px';

  // zoom in
  $scope.zoomIn = function() {
    $scope.image.style.width = $scope.zoomAmount + 'px';
  }

  // reset zoom
  $scope.zoomOut = function() {
    $scope.image.style.width = $scope.imageHolderDetails.width + 'px';
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Template</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Gummy bears anyone?</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content id="img-holder" scroll="true" overflow-scroll="false" locking="false" direction="xy">
    <img id="image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/55825/gold-bear-gummi-bears-bear-yellow-55825.jpeg">
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-royal">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="zoomOut()">
      <i class="icon ion-minus"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="zoomIn()">
      <i class="icon ion-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize()`

http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/eZLZdx

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I experienced working with accordions in Ionic. The advice I was given was to use the following code after your actions to automatically update the scrollable area (after zoom in or out):

```
    $timeout($ionicScrollDelegate.resize, 100);
```

The use of `$timeout` is required to ensure `$scope.apply()` is called properly. I found using a value of `0` for my timeout was not sufficient and opted to use 100 milliseconds. Again this was advice I found on the Ionic forums. You should check out `$ioncScrollDelegate` and it's associated directives in the docs for more information.